# How do I query with '.includes' across more than two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have the following associations:

```
class Captain
  has_many :boats
end

class Boat
  belongs_to :captain
  has_many :classifications
end

class Classification
  has_many :boats
end
```

**I want to find out which captains have boats that have classifications with :name attributes of "catamaran."**

This has been my best guess so far:
`Captain.includes(:boats, :classifications).where(:boats => {:classifications => {:name => "catamaran"}})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Captain.joins(boats: :classifications).where(classifications: { name: "catamaran" })
```

This query results in following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM `captains` 
   INNER JOIN `boats` ON `boats`.`captain_id` = `captains`.`id` 
   INNER JOIN `join_table` ON `join_table`.`boat_id` = `boat`.`id`     
   INNER JOIN `classifications` ON `join_table`.`classification_id` = `classifications`.id
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sujan Adiga has right!

If you use the `include` method, active record generate 2 separates sql query. The first for your main Model, and the second for your inclued model. But you don't have access on the included model in your first query.
When you use the `joins` method, active record generate sql query with joins statement. So you can use the joined model in your clause `where`.